# gem forgets installed package

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-20.04

When I `sudo gem install --verbose colorls`, it succeeds.

```
HEAD https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=colorls
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=addressable,clocale,filesize,manpages,rainbow,unicode-display_width
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=public_suffix
200 OK
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/colorls-1.4.4/.gitignore
...
Successfully installed colorls-1.4.4
```

But afterwards, gem does not see the installed package. It does see other installed packages via `gem list`. But it does not list colorls, and `gem which colorls` fails.

I previously (a few versions before) I installed colorls from a locally cloned source, but I want the latest public version now.

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you tell us which package manager you're using, and which OS you're working on?

Comment: @jad OS is in tags, Ubuntu 20.04; package manager for Ruby is apt

Comment: Can you try installing the gem without `sudo` permission and see how it goes?

Comment: ```gem install colorls
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/pkg/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0 directory.``` weird, seems to be a different dir

Comment: @FelixDombek you've screwed up permissions by installing ruby as `sudo`, when you shouldn't have. You could try fixing it all with `chown -R ....` , or, just reinstall ruby without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to uninstall the ruby installed by your `apt` then reinstall ruby using a ruby manager `rbenv` or `rvm`, this should fix your permission and you will be able to install bundler without sudo permission then install your gems